# Putting variable in sql query and label name vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I put a variable in query string and in assigning label name. Is that possible? If it is then why my function does not work.

I've searched the `me.controls(label_name)` and found that it works but how come it does not work in my function.

```
Public Sub tallyRatingA()
    Try
        For n = 1 To 5
            For m = 5 To 1
                Call conn()
                query = "SELECT COUNT(a" & n & ") AS tallycount FROM evaluation where teacher_id = '" & tId & "' AND a" & n & " = " & m
                command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader
                While (reader.Read)
                    If reader.HasRows Then
                        tally_count = reader.GetString("tallycount")
                    Else
                        tally_count = 0
                    End If
                End While
                reader.Close()
                connection.Close()
                Call conn()
                query = "SELECT SUM(a" & n & ") AS tallytotal FROM evaluation where teacher_id = '" & tId & "' AND a" & n & " = " & m
                command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader
                While (reader.Read)
                    If reader.HasRows Then
                        tally_total = reader.GetString("tallytotal")
                        total = total + tally_total
                    Else
                        tally_total = 0
                    End If
                End While
                labelname = "a" & n & "_" & m
                Me.Controls(labelname).Text = tally_count & " ( fx: " & tally_total & " )"
                connection.Close()
                reader.Close()
                tally_total = 0
                tally_total = 0
                total = 0
                tally_count = 0
            Next m
        Next n
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion : Better way to retrieve value from DataReader is `reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("tallytotal"))`

Comment: Edit your secondary loop to `For m = 5 to 1 Step -1`

Comment: thanks @CraigJohnson it worked. but he primary for loop didnt work, any suggestion?

Comment: @ Leomel, any error?

Comment: @AngusChung It's working now. there's no error but the output i was expecting does not show up completely. The secondary loop is working now but the outer loop just execute once, i need it to loop until 5. any suggestion?

Comment: @ Leomel , are you here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the loop and add **IFNULL** to check the sum value.

**Before**

```
For m = 5 To 1

query = "SELECT SUM(a" & n & ") AS tallytotal FROM evaluation where teacher_id = '" & tId & "' AND a" & n & " = " & m
```

**After**

```
For m = 5 To 1 step -1

query = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(a" & n & "),0) AS tallytotal FROM evaluation where teacher_id = '" & tId & "' AND a" & n & " = " & m
```